# why am I getting forbidden error on my URL routes for login DRF API?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-knox

I have created a simple login API through django rest framework. Below is the code snippet:

### views.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser, AllowAny
from knox.views import LoginView as KLView
from knox.models import AuthToken

class loginAPIView(KLView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(loginAPIView, self).post(request, format=None)
```

### URLS.py

```
from django.urls import path
from knox import views as knox_views
from .views import UserRegisterView, loginAPIView


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', loginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    ]
```

Now when I do a POST request in postman with the email and the password. It throws error:

```
{
    "detail": "Invalid token."
}
```

Note:: Since I am using knox to generate token. So, when I do a new registeration I get token as well. See sample below:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": {
        "email": "test.test@test.com",
        "first_name": "est",
        "last_name": "Sah",
        "employee_code": "6124368",
        "contact": "7500078619",
        "dob": null
    },
    "token": "db058f23ecc70f4fa3de4ac69a04dc48bb7579a63aea1ad3d038ce59b1511890"
```

I tried both, password and token to authenticate, but I am getting the same error. In the cmd prompt where the dev server is running, I am seeing below message

```
[08/Apr/2021 15:26:33] "POST /apii/login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 27
Forbidden: /apii/login/
```

In the postman raw body, I am inserting below json data

```
{
    "email": "test.test@test.com",
    "password": "db058f23ecc70f4fa3de4ac69a04dc48bb7579a63aea1ad3d038ce59b1511890"
}
```

Below is the settings.py content for DRF

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        #'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Not sure if I am doing it the right way, please suggest.

httpie output

```
python.exe -m httpie 127.0.0.1:8000/apii/login/ 'Authorization: Token db058f23ecc70f4fa3de4ac69a04dc48bb7579a63aea1ad3d038ce59b1511890'

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 11:52:31 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.8
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to post using **httpie** from the command prompt?

```
$ http  http://127.0.0.1:8000/{your_path} 'Authorization: Token db058f23ecc70f4fa3de4ac69a04dc48bb7579a63aea1ad3d038ce59b1511890'
```

Comment: amusing windows 10, not sure if I can install this on windows platform. If there's any other tools compatible for windows, plz let m know.

Comment: I didn't test, but it should work. See here: https://httpie.io/docs#windows-etc . Once installed run c:\>python -m httpie http://127.0.0.1:8000/{your_path} 'Authorization: Token db058f23ecc70f4fa3de4ac69a04dc48bb7579a63aea1ad3d038ce59b1511890'

Comment: Thank you, I was able to download and use it. I got the output, which seems to be obvious. Please see my original post with the latest data.